# Abstract base Func with variable number of input parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate, func

First excuse the poorly written summary as I am not able to describe more precisely what I am looking for.

I have the following class:

```cs
public abstract class Table<T>
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> list;

    protected abstract Func<T, object[], bool> Func { get; }
    protected T Find(params object[] objects) => list.First(element => Func(element, objects));

}
```

Which contains and `abstract Func<T, object[], bool>` that each derived class has to implement. So for example, the following classes:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName;
}

public class Person2
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID;
}
```

Will have their corresponding `Table<T>` implementation like this:

```cs
public class TablePerson : Table<Person>
{
    protected override Func<Person, object[], bool> Func => (p, obj) 
    => p.FirstName == (string)obj[0];

    public Person GetPerson(string firstName) => Find(firstName);
}

public class TablePerson2 : Table<Person2>
{
    protected override Func<Person2, object[], bool> Func => (p, obj) 
    => p.FirstName == (string)obj[0] && p.LastName == (string)obj[1];

    public Person2 GetPerson2(string firstName, string lastName) => Find(firstName, lastName);
}

public class TableEmployee : Table<Employee>
{
    protected override Func<Employee, object[], bool> Func => (p, obj)
    => p.ID == (int)obj[0];

    public Employee GetEmployee(int id) => Find(id);
}
```

I am trying to change the `object[]` parameter of `Func<T, object[], bool>` to something that is type aware if possible. I am also not sure if this is the way it should be programmed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you might really are looking for is a ORM.... assuming that table is something db releated

Comment: What about `Table<TObject, TKey1, TKey2>` although you will need separate classes for each n-ary number of generic parameters.

Comment: @Mat table is only a class wrapping a list that resides in memory

Comment: @Charlieface I believe the combinatorial explosion of input parameters would become overwhelming pretty soon

Comment: Why? Like I said: you only need a new class for each *number* of parameters, so up to 8 or 10 different classes at most. `Table<TObject, TKey1>` `Table<TObject, TKey1, TKey2>` `Table<TObject, TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>` etc. You can abstract out some functionality into a non-generic base class which each inherits

Comment: `protected abstract Func<T, dynamic[], bool> Func { get; }` gets rid of the casts.  That said I would keep them, not sure what's wrong with the way you have it now.

Comment: you can also use inMemory database with a lot of ORMs. For example Enity Framework. This also benefits that you can switch the datasource to something more useful than in memory in the future without headache. I already worked with "abstract the ORM away" solutions. For me this is the worst anti pattern you can go  for... it's hard to come up with something more useful than a community of millions of developers...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651007/using-entity-framework-core-3-1-with-useinmemorydatabase-option-in-serviceprovid